# splitting string values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, ejs

I have a string of words (item names) being passed to my front end from the database I have set up. It is all working great, but I in my table in html, I have the item name in a loop, so the item names are stuck together if there is more than one item, like so:  `Item name1Item name2`

I am passing them through to the front end using an ejs loop, and <%= data[i].ITEMNAME %>, which passes the values from the database in that specific row. So they are always changing depending on the item name. An example:
I need them like `Item name1, Item name2`

I have this in my script so far.

```
var itemNameSplit = '<%= data[i].ITEMNAME %>';
var splitResponse = itemNameSplit.split(" ");
document.write("<td>" + splitResponse + "</td>")
```

however, this puts a comma after every word, not the end of the item name, like so:

```
Item,name,1Item,name,2
```

when again, I need it like

```
Item name1, Item name2
```

its slipping my mind how to do this, thanks in advance for the help! much appreciated:)

Comment: hi there is no space between `Item name1(here)Item name2` ?

Comment: yes, my items are these put together like this: `All Purpose ShineBlue Rubber on Grey Polly Cotten Gloves`

Comment: There is no consistency in your data! I believe data you're receiving from the service should be managed. not from the front-end.

Comment: I am just doing a simple `select * from table` and passing the data, then passing data to front end and displaying in a table using ejs. not sure how I could manage it from backend, unless there's a way to split the data in nodejs backend, then it might work

Comment: do you just need a comma with a space after each `<%= data[i].ITEMNAME %>`?

Comment: The problem with that is that stores the entire string in it, so putting a comma with a space would just result in the same result, but with a comma and a soace at the end of the entire string. ‘Item 1Item 2, ‘

Comment: I thought `<%= data[i].ITEMNAME %>` is `name1` etc.

Comment: Maybe this is something to do with EJS - the templating language rather than the js.

Comment: @JoePythonKing I couldn’t find anything online about it, because I am actually passing the values of the item through as a string, in ejs that is <%= data[i].ITEMNANE %>, so I can’t really think of a reason how it could be a templating issue, I thought about handling it backend but it doesn’t really change much.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var splitResponse = itemNameSplit.split("Item").join(", Item").replace(", ", "");
```

Comment: Item name is used in general sense above,,it can vary

Comment: I tried what you said @blaz and it came back same as before `All Purpose ShineBlue Rubber on Grey Polly Cotten Gloves`

Comment: @Gianluca I believe you need to provide a more generic sample of data in your question. I misunderstood that all your separated data start with 'Item', and there are others with same assumption in the comment section too.

Comment: Sure! Apologies for the mixup. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

//I misread the problem - this just makes 1 comma in cycle of 2, a space

```
  a="Item,name,1Item,name,2"
    b=a.split(",")
    c=b.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) =>{
      return currentIndex % 2 ?(accumulator + " " +  currentValue) :(accumulator + "," +  currentValue)
    })
    
    
    console.log(c)
    //Item name,1Item name,2
```

Comment: I tried this with the `a` variable = `<%= data [I].ITEMNAME %>`, and it came back with the same response. im thinking the only thing that might work is of theres a way to split the string up where there is conjoining words...