# splitting words at camelCase javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, ejs

I have a string like so:

```
all purpose shineBlue gloves
```

when I need them to be like

```
all purpose shine, blue gloves
```

is this possible with javascript?

my code is

```
 var itemNameSplit = '<%= data[i].ITEMNAME %>';
 var splitResponse = itemNameSplit.split("");
 document.write("<td>" + splitResponse + "</td>")
```

but its returning:

```
A,l,l, ,P,u,r,p,o,s,e, ,S,h,i,n,e,B,l,u,e, ,R,u,b,b,e,r, ,o,n, ,G,r,e,y, ,P,o,l,l,y, ,C,o,t,t,e,n, ,G,l,o,v,e,s
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [splitting string values using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65501932/splitting-string-values-using-javascript)

Comment: @Gianluca I don't think your problem is that straightforward. To split words you need to know these words and their boundaries. That implies using a word dictionary. Secondly, your desired output also needs added punctuation in the sentence. Considering this, you might need to look at NL processing APIs if that's something viable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution assuming there is only one camelCase instance in the string.

```
var s = 'all purpose shineBlue gloves'
var regex = /[A-Z]/g
var changeUpper = s.charAt(s.search(regex)).toLowerCase()
var solution = s.split(regex).join(`, ${changeUpper}`)
document.write("<td>" + solution + "</td>")
```

In case there are multiple camelCase instances in the string you can use the following solution

```
var s = 'all purpose shineBlue gloves with anotherCamel'
var regex = /[A-Z]/g
var transform = s.split(' ')
var map = transform.map((word) => {
  if (word.search(regex) != -1) {
    var changeUpper = word.charAt(word.search(regex)).toLowerCase()
    var splitWord = word.split(regex).join(`, ${changeUpper}`)
    return splitWord
  } else {
    return word
  }
})
var solution = map.join(' ')
document.write('<td>' + solution + '</td>')
```

Comment: I think this would work, but the value of the variable you set, `s`, won't always be `all purpose shineBlue gloves with anotherCamel`. It will change depending on what the value of `data[I].ITEMNAME` is. when I used solutions1 you gave with `data[I].ITEMNAME, I got the result `, all , aurpose , aubricant, alue , aubber on , arey , aolly , aotten , aloves`. none the less still appreciate you helping out.

Comment: Yeah, the first solution is only valid for a sentence that has 1 camelCase instance because it only looks at the first time there is an uppercase character. If you are looping through a set of strings (which I'm guessing that's what the data[i].ITEMNAME is doing) the second solution might be best.

Comment: I tried the second solution as well, and it came out with a nicer looking answer, but still didn’t split the string up properly. Is there anything else I could try or look for more?

Comment: Could you show the full object (data[i]) where you are getting the properties? (data[i].ITEMNAME). This way I can understand better the objective and potential tweaks to the code.